# How to change the screenshot path in Rails 5.1 system test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Using Rails 5.1.2
Creating a system test and using the take_screenshot method.

How do i change the location these screenshots are created at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [image path](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper.rb#L44) is hardcoded in, so you won't be able to change it currently. Probably wouldn't be too difficult to change if you wanted to open an issue over there or create a pull request for them.

Comment: Thanks, the answers it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on CI, here's the solution I came up with. In my setup I already had a "test-runner.sh" script, with the rspec invocation at the end. There's probably also some sort of `after_script:` setting in the yml config also available, but I didn't look into it.

```sh
rspec ......

status=$?

# /tmp/test-results is where CircleCI looks for "artifacts" which it makes
# available for download after a test run
[ -d "tmp/screenshots" ] && cp -a tmp/screenshots /tmp/test-results/

exit $status
```